# Possible to use different forms authentication cookie names for multiple virtual directories mapped to one physical directory?

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

Using ASP.NET 2.0, IIS 7.

I have an ASP.NET application using forms authentication setup as follows in web.config :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH_LIVE" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="1440" path="/" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"/>
</authentication>
```

There are two IIS virtual directories mapped to the one physical directory. Since they map to the same physical directory, they both use the cookieName : ".ASPXAUTH_LIVE". 
Is there some way to get the two virtual directories to use different cookie names ? I know I could make multiple copies of the physical directory, and change the name attribute in the web.config, but I'd rather not have to maintain multiple physical directories.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot guarantee this will be of any assistance, but my first instinct would be to override the defaults for each virtual directory by adding a `<location>` element to your site's root web.config:

```
<location path="Path/To/Virtual/Directory">
  <system.web>
    <authentication>
      <forms name=".ASPXAUTH_LIVE2" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

At first blush I expect this to fail miserably, but if nothing else it's an idea to test. I apologize for not trying the configuration myself but this would require a bit of work on my part to configure a working test project.

Comment: i don't think this will work in my case, but thanks for trying.